# Cannot change OUT variable in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, case

I try to change `OUT` variable in stored procedure. Before call procedure I set `my_variable` to 9. I have no errors, but after `CALL` statement variable is `NULL`

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE getAllMen(OUT my_variable int)

BEGIN
    CASE my_variable 
    WHEN my_variable <= 10 THEN SELECT 44 INTO my_variable;
    WHEN my_variable > 10 THEN SELECT 55 INTO my_variable;
    ELSE BEGIN END; 
END CASE;
END


SET @start_id = 9;

SELECT @start_id;

CALL getAllMen(@start_id);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getAllMen`;

CREATE PROCEDURE `getAllMen`(
  /*OUT `my_variable` INT*/
  INOUT `my_variable` INT
)
BEGIN
  CASE/* `my_variable` */
    WHEN `my_variable` <= 10 THEN
      SELECT 44 INTO `my_variable`;
    WHEN `my_variable` > 10 THEN
      SELECT 55 INTO `my_variable`;
  END CASE;
END;

SET @`start_id` := 9;

SELECT @`start_id`;

CALL `getAllMen`(@`start_id`);

SELECT @`start_id`;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/55nfuDAAvymbjFjLnLJ8sv/2).

**UPDATE**

See documentation:

> [13.1.16 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION
>   Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)
>
> ...
>
> An `OUT` parameter passes a value from the procedure back to the
>   caller. Its initial value is `NULL` within the procedure, and its
>   value is visible to the caller when the procedure returns.
>
> ...

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. But why I need change `OUT` on `INOUT`? If I set `OUT` and try to create procedure, I'll have ` Case not found for CASE statement` error, why?